# Unix time +n days on Solaris without date -d option

Tags: perl, date, unix, solaris

I am looking for a way to return date plus (or minus) n days.  Our Solaris 10 system does not have the -d option for date, not even under /usr/xpg4/bin/date.

I considered perl, found a couple of examples on another thread, but system does not include

```
use Time::ParseDate;
use Time::CTime;
```

nor

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
```

Our system is heavily regulated, so I cannot expect to install any utilities or libraries that are not already here.

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib

Comment: `Time::Piece` is a core Perl module

Comment:  ...yup, since version 5.10

Comment: *Our Solaris 10 system does not have the -d option for date, not even under /usr/xpg4/bin/date.* That's because the `-d` option is a non-standard GNU extension to the [POSIX standard `date` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html).

Comment: @JimR, please show some sample input and output: Do you mean "today minus n days"? Or some arbitrary date?

Comment: @glennjackman For example, date -d "+2 days"  Would return "Sun  May 20 15:12:17 EDT 2018"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want.

Some examples that might help:

```
perl -e'$days=shift; print "".localtime(time + $days*24*3600)' 3      #in 3 days
Thu Apr 19 23:13:53 2018

perl -e'$days=shift; print "".localtime(time + $days*24*3600)' -- -7  #a week ago
Mon Apr  9 23:14:16 2018

chmod +x date_formatted.pl
cat date_formatted.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
for(@ARGV){
  my @lt=localtime( time() + $_*24*3600 );
  printf "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d\n",
    $lt[5]+1900,
    $lt[4]+1,
    @lt[3,2,1,0];
}

./date_formatted.pl -2
2018-04-14T23:25:21

./date_formatted.pl 3
2018-04-19T23:25:21

./date_formatted.pl 0.5
2018-04-17T11:25:21

./date_formatted.pl -1 0 1
2018-04-15T23:25:21
2018-04-16T23:25:21
2018-04-17T23:25:21
```

If you are allowed to, install `Date::Manip` and have a look at http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.70/lib/Date/Manip/Examples.pod#TO_ADD_AN_AMOUNT_OF_TIME_TO_A_DATE

Comment: Yep, these all work well.  What is the purpose of the -- in you 2nd example?  Sadly, I am not able to install anything due to our regulated environment.

Comment: Try without `--` and see what happens! `--` means end of options (at least in bash, and probably most if not all other unix/gnu/linux shells as well). Without that the `-7` days would be seen as an command line option to perl itself, not a negative integer argument for my little one-liner program.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e 'use strict;use warnings;use POSIX; my $date_folder_to_be_deleted=strftime "%Y-%m-%d",localtime(time() - 24*60*60); print "$date_folder_to_be_deleted"'
```

Hope this works if yes you can use for loop to get different days by multiplying loop variable with 24*60*60*n

Answer (score 1):

Perl's `Time::Piece` module has been part of the core distribution since perl v5.10

You don't say what format you want the date in, but this will generate the date one day ahead in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
perl -MTime::Piece -E 'say((gmtime()+24*60*60)->ymd)'
```

#### output

```
2018-04-17
```

Comment: No joy.  We seem to have perl 5.8.4.  perl -MTime::Piece -E 'say((gmtime()+24*60*60)->ymd)'
Unrecognized switch: -E  (-h will show valid options).

Comment: @JimR: That's ridiculous. That version is fourteen years old! There's a slim  chance that you have `Time::Piece`, so try `perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print((gmtime()+24*60*60)->ymd, "\n")'` Otherwise you'll have to look at installing a private copy. How can they expect you to work with a "heavily-regulated" out-of-date system?

Comment: @Borodin, "enterprise"

Comment: @JimR, you should be able to use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) to install more a modern perl release into your home directory.

Comment: @glennjackman As I stated in my original post, "Our system is heavily regulated, so I cannot expect to install any utilities or libraries that are not already here"